# Unable to load angular controller file while running server side using nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

when the controller code is written in the same html file, code works.
But as soon as I separate the controller code into myController.js file and mention the js file in the src attribut I get an $injector module error.
This is the error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:4547 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. 
If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

This is my angular controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.submitForm=function(){ 

$http({
   method:"POST",
   url:"http://localhost:7000/frmAng/",
   headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
   data : {
       name : $scope.name,
       pwd : $scope.pwd
   }
}).then(function(response) {
      $scope.resFrmServer = response.data;
   },function(response){
      $scope.resFrmServer = response.statusText;
    });
  };  
}]);
```

How do I overcome this ? As, I want to separate out all js files for further minification.

Complete html file with angular code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js'></script>
</head>    
<body>



<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" align="center" > 

<hr>

<form >
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"  required autofocus><br><br>
     Password:<input type="password" ng-model="pwd"><br><br> 
    <input type="submit" ng-click="submitForm()" text="Submit">
</form>
<h1>{{resFrmServer}}</h1>     
</div>
<script >
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submitForm=function(){ 
$http({
   method:"POST",
   url:"http://localhost:7000/frmAng/",
   headers : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
   data : {
       name : $scope.name,
       pwd : $scope.pwd
   }
}).then(function(response) {
      $scope.resFrmServer = response.data;

   },function(response){
      $scope.resFrmServer = response.statusText;          
    });
  };  
}]);

</script>
```

Comment: can you post html code?

Comment: Fix your server (node) routing or path to script file. Showing us the angular code doesn't tell us why the 404 occurs

Comment: @Scarecrow, I've updated the post with the html code

Comment: @charlietfl, there's no issue with the route, route works well with the above code. The  issue is when I separate the angular code into a separate .js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are using express.js for enabling web provider.

If you are using express.js, please use following code for supplying static files

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

where public is the directory, where all static files are available.

Then please place your js file, which contains angular module and controller code, in public directory and include it from html file.

Comment: Thanks @Sagar, just updated my code with express.static middleware func.

Answer (score 0):

```
// [ route.js ]
app.get('/myController.js',function(req,res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + "/client/" + "myController.js");
});
```

adding a route to my controller, this was the missing part.
As, I'm new to node, I wasn't aware that files mentioned in the "src" of the "script" tag too requires routes. I thought node'll simply use the file protocol to fetch those files.

**Comment by Patrick is a better workaround.**

Comment: If you're using express, you can solve this by using the `express.static` call, as explained [in the docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. That worked and also reduced my code. Thanks once again